# IOS Where To Persist Current User from Back-end

Tags: ios, core-data, nscoding

I am using an IOS app with a Rails Back-end. When the user opens the app, I want to query its profile from the server and set a current user method in order to call it somewhere else in the app without querying it again from the server.

I would also like to store it so that the profile is saved to the disk and can viewed offline, including the profile picture.

What is a good storage solution for the current user and its profile picture? The different solutions I am thinking about are Core Data (because I already use in the app), and NSKeyedArchiver.

Any recommendations or ideas on which solution to adopt?

Comment: What details are you talking about -> keychain

Comment: Already using keychain for security, I am talking about profile details such as name, location, gender, age etc..

Comment: That's personally identifiable info -> keychain

Comment: The profile is larger than that, at least 12-15 fields, isn't there a better place than keychain? And what about the profile image?

Comment: Just because it is personal information, it doesn't need to go in the keychain. You can store it in the documents directory and set appropriate file security on it if you need to. I would probably use an archiver and just store the image as a file.